# Asymptotics of $(\cosh(x+c)-\cosh(c))^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

let $c>0$ be a constant and consider the function $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cosh(x+c)-\cosh(c)}}, x>0.$$

I'm wondering how the asymptotic expansion for $x\downarrow 0$ look like!? In case of $c=0$ the asymptotics is quite easy. Unfortunately the proof cannot be applied to this case. How can I get the asymptotics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Taylor expansion:
$$
\cosh(x+c)=\cosh c+(\sinh c)\,x+O(x^2).
$$
Then
$$
\sqrt{\cosh(x+c)-\cosh c}=\sqrt{(\sinh c)\,x+O(x^2)}=\sqrt{(\sinh c)\,x}+O(x^{3/2})
$$
and
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cosh(x+c)-\cosh(c)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\sinh c)\,x}}+O(x^{1/2}).$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have some further questions. Can you explain to me how you get $\sqrt{sinh(c)x+O(x^2)}=\sqrt{sinh(c)x}+ O(x^{3/2})$? I just could prove $O(x^{1/2})$ instead of $O(x^{3/2})$. Is there a typo in your answer or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: $$\sqrt{a\,x+O(x^2)}=\sqrt{a\,x}\,\sqrt{1+O(x)}$$ and $$\sqrt{1+O(x)}=1+O(x).$$